# Create .cshtml file programmatically in ASP.NET Core Web API using C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create `.cshtml` file programmatically. I have a page that will have html fields to specify what all fields contains, on saving this should create a `.cshtml` file in the `C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\DynamicForms\DynamicForms\Views\Home` folder. How can I achieve this?

I am trying to generate `.cshtml` through code.

Comment: My 2p - I would think you'd be better off having a single .cshtml that read the desired fields and render everything dynamically. Otherwise you're having to create a new view every time there's even the slightest change which means you will probably have to think about management of these views including clean up.

Comment: My goal is to generate forms through code automation in which there will be one UI for specifying html form fields then the form will be getting ready with autogenerated .cshtml file. can you please suggest to me how can I do?

Comment: The view should be data driven and add fields as defined in some data structure (generated from the _"specifying html form fields"_)

Comment: yes Farid Uddain, It was worked. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create .cshtml file programmatically. I have a page that
> will have html fields to specify what all fields contains, on saving
> this should create a .cshtml file in the
> C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\DynamicForms\DynamicForms\Views\Home
> folder. How can I achieve this?

Well, there's nothing wrong creating `.cshtml` file and you can create the file  same as other file read/write operation using `System.IO.File` operation. Just like below:

```
 var cshtmlcontent = @"@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Book>
    <table class=""table table table-bordered"">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Book Id
                <th>Title
                <th>Description
                <th>Author Name
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                    <td>@item.Author?.Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Kiron\GitDemoApp\DotNet6MVCWebApp\wwwroot\Test.cshtml", cshtmlcontent);
```

[image]

[image]

However, you cannot run this file directly, because, in asp.net core MVC `.cshtml` files are rendered based on your controller and action route definition, therefore, your newly created wouldn't have any designated route for that so it wouldn't compile and run the same way .cshtml razor page does.

On the other hand, you even can write that using response.write or even inside view folder and during that time, your application compiler will detected the changes and program would restered each time you will create dynammic .cshtml file, that would lead to below pop-ups:

[image]

In addition to this, you can use [ICompositeViewEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.icompositeviewengine?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to render dynamic but still requried relevant controller and action to render view engine.